# Why my 3d background is not loading in ThreeJS?

Tags: three.js

I'm using CubeTextureLoader for a 3d background of 2 images and it aint working. Even though the path to images is fine and I get the images working fine in TextureLoader.

```
import * as THREE from "three"
import {OrbitControls} from "three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js"
import * as dat from "dat.gui"

import nebula from './images/nebula.jpg'
import stars from './images/stars.jpg'

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true });
renderer.shadowMap.enabled=true
renderer.setClearColor(0x590d18, 1);
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const scene = new THREE.Scene();

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
  75,
  window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
  0.1,
  1000
);

const orbit=new OrbitControls(camera,renderer.domElement)

const axesHelper = new THREE.AxesHelper(2);
scene.add(axesHelper);

camera.position.set(-10, 30, 30);
orbit.update()


const planeGeometry=new THREE.PlaneGeometry(30,30)
const planeMaterial=new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
  color:0xffffff,
  side:THREE.DoubleSide  
})
const plane=new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry,planeMaterial)
scene.add(plane)
plane.rotation.x=-0.5*Math.PI
plane.receiveShadow=true

const gridHelper=new THREE.GridHelper(30)
scene.add(gridHelper)

const sphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(4,50,50);
const sphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
  color: 0x0000ff,
  wireframe:false,
});
const sphere = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry, sphereMaterial);
scene.add(sphere);
sphere.position.set(-10,4,4)
sphere.castShadow=true


const spotLight=new THREE.SpotLight(0xFFFFFF)
scene.add(spotLight)
spotLight.position.set(-100,100,0)
spotLight.castShadow=true
spotLight.angle=0.2

const sLightHelper=new THREE.SpotLightHelper(spotLight)
scene.add(sLightHelper)

scene.fog=new THREE.FogExp2(0xFFFFFF,0.02)

//loading an image
//const textureLoader=new THREE.TextureLoader()
//scene.background=textureLoader.load(stars)                   THIS WORKS
const cubeTextureLoader=new THREE.CubeTextureLoader()          THIS DONT
scene.background=cubeTextureLoader.load([
stars,
stars,
nebula,
stars,
stars,
stars
 ])



const gui=new dat.GUI()
const options={
  sphereColor:'#ffea00',
  wireframe:false,
  speed:0.01,
  angle:0.2,
  penumbra:0,
  intensity:1
}
gui.addColor(options,'sphereColor').onChange(function(e){
  sphere.material.color.set(e)
})
gui.add(options,'wireframe').onChange(function(e){
  sphere.material.wireframe=e
})
gui.add(options,"speed",0,0.1)
gui.add(options,"angle",0,1)
gui.add(options,"penumbra",0,1)
gui.add(options,"intensity",0,1)

let step=0
function animate(time) {
  box.rotation.x = time/1000;
  box.rotation.y = time/1000;

  step+=options.speed
  sphere.position.y=10*Math.abs(Math.sin(step))

  spotLight.angle=options.angle;
  spotLight.penumbra=options.penumbra;
  spotLight.intensity=options.intensity;
  sLightHelper.update()

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

renderer.setAnimationLoop(animate)
```

I was expecting a 3d background , but instead I get the original black color.

I'm using CubeTextureLoader for a 3d background of 2 images and it aint working. Even though the path to images is fine and I get the images working fine in TextureLoader.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a while back and it turns out all the faces of the `CubeTextureLoader` must be squares.

So, cropping the images to have a *1:1 dimension* might work.